# Tasker double WiFi activation with 'or' statement

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, tasker, profiles

I have a Tasker app on my tablet, I want to make a profile which will trigger silent mode when 2 conditions are met: Connection with WiFi Network A is lost and either network B or C is connected. I want this profile to be turned off when network A is connected again. I assume that some sort of variable has to be used for the 'B or C' function.

How can I do this? Also can please walk me through how to assign variables if any.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify quite a bit of logic in just the contexts. Having a profile with multiple contexts would be the easiest way to accomplish this. Remember that all contexts have to be met sequentially before the task(s) will fire. Also, the Wifi Connected context [will accept multiple SSIDs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tasker/Fy4fPzfLRA8) by using [pattern matching](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/matching.html). In this case a `/` equals logical OR. Try the following:

Profile:

- Context: [Wifi Connected] SSID="NetworkA", Invert=Yes
- Context: [Wifi Connected] SSID="NetworkB/NetworkC"
- Task(s): Ringtone silence settings of your choice

This means that the task(s) will fire if Network A is not connected AND Network B OR Network C are connected. As soon either condition is lost the task will exit.

Comment: Just for clarification: You can enter multiple SSIDs in that text field, separated by a `/`, and *Tasker* interprets that as "one of those"? Have you tried? The [Tasker UserGuide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/sh_index.html) doesn't mention that, but simply says *SSID: the SSID of the AP e.g. SKY34312*.

Comment: Yes. Check out the Pattern Matching section of the User Guide (linked above). Simple Matching (versus Regex Matching) "is used ... in text parameters of State and Event contexts." The SSID parameter in the Wifi Connected context is such a field. One of the matching rules is "`/` means 'or', it divides up multiple possible matches."

Comment: I must have missed that part all those years! Thanks for the enlightment! That makes some other tasks much easier. Need to go over my repo with that :)